# How to use the same melpa directoy for different emacs distrubitions

Tags: package-repositories

I have several emacs distributions (scimax, spacemacs, vanilla emacs, etc.) which all uses their own melpa directory. I want them all to use the same elpa (or melpa or gnu) directory to save some place.

For example, I have a "init.el" file in my vanilla emacs directory (~/.emacs.d/init.el). I want "Vanilla emacs" to look up elpa files inside in my scimax directory (~/emacs/scimax/.emacs.d/elpa) and download future elpa files inside the scimax's elpa directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your best option is to install your packages normally in one of the emacs distributions and then symlink to the others. For example, after you install your vanilla emacs packages, create a symlink to spacemacs like this: `ln -s ~/.emacs.d/elpa ~/.spacemacs.d/`

Comment: The symlink goods look. I wonder it may create a problem in the future.

Comment: If you set it up properly I don't think it would create any problem